# how to have vuejs set to checked the correct radio button

Tags: vuejs2

I have a set of radio buttons and want to set the correct choice. I have a value financing.is_reamortizable which should reflect whether the end user has this clicked. How could / should I bind this or check via computed property or other choice?

```
   <div class='row both10'>
      <div class='col-md-4 input-group'>
        Reamortization Available:
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-3 input-group'>
        Yes<input type='radio' name='financing[is_reamortizable]' value="true" v-bind:value="financing.is_reamortizable" />
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-3 input-group'>
        No<input type='radio' name='financing[is_reamortizable]' value="false" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation shows that you should set `v-model` on both radio buttons to the same variable (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio).  You don't need `v-bind:value` in this instance because your values are static (`true` and `false`).

So your code would become:

```
   <div class='row both10'>
      <div class='col-md-4 input-group'>
        Reamortization Available:
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-3 input-group'>
        Yes<input type='radio' name='financing[is_reamortizable]' value="true" v-model="financing.is_reamortizable" />
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-3 input-group'>
        No<input type='radio' name='financing[is_reamortizable]' value="false" v-model="financing.is_reamortizable"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thx - I saw that but I am using this in a modal so I need to decouple the two instances. I don't think v-model would be the right choice then.